# Corrupted folders content on USB flash drive

Tags: usb, mount, fat32, data-corruption

I'm using XUBUNTU (Linux apollon 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I insert an USB flashdrive.
It mounts correctly.

```
$lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdg      8:96   1   3,8G  0 disk 
└─sdg1   8:97   1   3,8G  0 part /media/marcus/FLASHDRIVE
```

I can access almost all data within the file explorer.
But in the file structure 5 folders give me the same error:

```
Failed to open directory Error when getting information for file '/media/FLASHDRIVE/Folder/$%&$$·$$$' : Input/output error
```

I try to copy/paste the content of one folder of the flashdrive to another place on my hard drive and I get a message like "This folder containts 81GB of data, do you want to continue?"

With Terminal, I can enter the folder, and list the content.

```
ls: cannot access ''$'\020''8'$'\024''l?+{v.y?'$'\003': Input/output error
ls: cannot access ''$'\272''xqh'$'\351''9?d.*'$'\254\346': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'e)'$'\027\034''|y'$'\245'',.`'$'\261''?': Input/output error
////TRUNCATED/////
total 496519552
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? zv?????j.}ó0
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? zv?????j.}ó0
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? zv?????j.}ó0
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? zv?????j.}ó0
-????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ?{°åY-W./:.
-????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ?{°åY-W./:.
-????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ?{°åY-W./:.
-????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ?{°åY-W./:.
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? /ydw?}d.     x
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? /ydw?}d.     x
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? /ydw?}d.     x
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? /ydw?}d.     x
////TRUNCATED/////
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 3608236668 nov  6  1981 "?!eėórr.0y
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 3608236668 nov  6  1981 "?!eėórr.0y
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 3608236668 nov  6  1981 "?!eėórr.0y
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 3608236668 nov  6  1981 "?!eėórr.0y
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3553122376 gen 13  1985 3`į,?9?.MM
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3553122376 gen 13  1985 3`į,?9?.MM
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3553122376 gen 13  1985 3`į,?9?.MM
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3553122376 gen 13  1985 3`į,?9?.MM
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  365811762 mar  1  1985 p?)t?î.???
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  365811762 mar  1  1985 p?)t?î.???
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  365811762 mar  1  1985 p?)t?î.???
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  365811762 mar  1  1985 p?)t?î.???
////TRUNCATED/////
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2674107682 mai 27  2104 ?ų?mũ??>.?-w
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2674107682 mai 27  2104 ?ų?mũ??>.?-w
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2674107682 mai 27  2104 ?ų?mũ??>.?-w
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2674107682 mai 27  2104 ?ų?mũ??>.?-w
```

Seems there is groups of 4 similars entries.
File size a so "wrongly" HUGE.
Dates are from past to future.

By now, I've copied the remaing and healthy data.
I `dd`ed the flash drive.

I'd like to know what might be the reason of this failure.
And I hope there is a way to "rebuild" the original data.

Many thanks in advance!